# iOS Prevent Scrolling of Document Only

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, scroll

I have been using this in Javascript for preventing scrolling of my entire app:

```
function preventBehavior(e) {
e.preventDefault();
}
document.addEventListener("touchmove", preventBehavior, false);
```

However, this also prevents any `overflow:scroll` elements from having the ability to do so.

What is also annoying, is that this prevents the onClick feature from working correctly. In jQuery, if I bind a function to the `click` event, the function will still execute if you tap down on the element, but then slide your finger away before releasing it.

Is there a better way to prevent the user from scrolling the document (in other words, I don't want the window to move), that does not have the above issues?